# Circular dependency with using directive where forward declarations don't work

Tags: c++, using, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

I'm working with a codebase where I can't solve this circular dependency:

foo.h

```
class Foo
{
public:
  using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<Foo>;
  using ConstPtr = std::shared_ptr<const Foo>;

  void setter(const Bar::Ptr& bar_ptr) {};

private:
  Bar::WeakPtr bar_ptr_;
};
```

and

bar.h

```
class Bar
{
public:
  using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<Bar>;
  using ConstPtr = std::shared_ptr<const Bar>;
  using WeakPtr = std::weak_ptr<Bar>;

  Bar(Foo::ConstPtr foo_ptr) : foo_ptr_(std::move(foo_ptr)) {};

private:
  Foo::ConstPtr foo_ptr_;
};
```

It was previously compiling because there was an external header where:

```
using FooPtr = std::shared_ptr<Foo>;
using FooConstPtr = std::shared_ptr<const Foo>;
using BarPtr = std::shared_ptr<Bar>;
```

But since consistency is sought after, I'd like to have `Foo::Ptr`, `Foo::ConstPtr`, `Bar::Ptr`. Any chance I can get it?

[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e31e4ae3f3c99821)

EDIT: added the `Bar::WeakPtr` which was previously missing since I thought I was already in trouble.

Comment: Can you explain the requirement of `using` and not using a variable?

Comment: @cigien: No, these aren't nested

Comment: @jackw11111 `using` is to hide the fact that it's a `std::shared_ptr` instead of a `boost::shared_ptr` sometimes soon. It's actually `using Ptr = my_namespace::shared_ptr<Foo>;`

Comment: `Foo` doesn't have a `Bar::Ptr` member that `setter()` assigns to, in fact `setter()` doesn't participate in shared ownership of `Bar` at all, so it shouldn't be taking a `shared_ptr<Bar>` at all (https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/), thus you could break the circular dependency by changing `Foo::setter()` to `void setter(const Bar* bar_ptr)` and then forward-declare `Bar`

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're almost right, I just checked and `Foo` has a `Bar::WeakPtr`. I simplified too much the example, let me fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This is arguably a deficiency of C++. You cannot declare just some public names of a class without including the whole class definition. In this setting, I am afraid your circular dependency cannot be resolved - at least not in a way that won't bite you in some way in the future.

However, as an alternative, consider using a template definitions outside of the subject class. It changes the order of terms, but not the overall meaning:

```
template<class T>
struct PtrStruct {
    using type = std::shared_ptr<T>;
};

template<class T>
using Ptr = typename PtrStruct<T>::type;

template<class T>
struct ConstPtrStruct {
    using type = std::shared_ptr<const T>;
};

template<class T>
using ConstPtr = typename PtrStruct<const T>::type;
```

In this setting your `Foo::Ptr` becomes `Ptr<Foo>` and `Foo::ConstPtr` becomes `ConstPtr<Foo>`. You still can:

- at a later stage replace `std::shared_ptr` with something different at a single place where `PtrStruct` is defined. Rest of the code will compile without a change, as long as the used interface didn't change.
- specialize `PtrStruct` for specific `T` if it should be something different than the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If consistency is sought after,  do not create ill-formed structures. You can try something like:

```cpp
// Foo.h

class Bar;

class Foo
{
public:
  using BarPtr = std::shared_ptr<Bar>;

  void setter( BarPtr bar_ptr)
  {}
};


// Bar.h

class Foo;

class Bar
{
public:
  using ConstFooPtr=std::shared_ptr<const Foo>;

  Bar( ConstFooPtr foo_ptr)
      : foo_ptr_( std::move( foo_ptr))
  {}

private:
  ConstFooPtr foo_ptr_;
};
```

Comment: You got the `Ptr` and `ConstPtr` in the classes swapped

Comment: In original post there seems to be a discrepancy in bar.h: the constructor takes a shared_pointer to const Foo object and tries to store in shared_ptr to non-const Foo object.

Comment: @Andreas_75 fixed